# Access an AJAX Enabled WCF from outside?

Tags: wcf, asp.net-ajax

Is it possible to access an AJAX enabled WCF from an external website i.e. not the website in which this ajax enabled WCF is hosted?

Comment: You have to proxy it somehow. In ASP.NET the best way to do this is to request the information from the server as a separate call and then return the content to the request from your site. Here is a nice article about one way to do it: https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/calling-cross-domain-web-services-in-ajax/

Comment: Pow-Iam  - Can you put this as a separate post so I can mark it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

When you need to access something across domains, due to security issues you must have the server access this information and then pass it back to your client.

[Chris Ullman of simple talk](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/calling-cross-domain-web-services-in-ajax/) does a `great job` detailing your proxy options.